# IBM MQ msgId null character

Tags: queue, websphere, mq

I put a message in queue,as I know queue manager sets msgId value.
When I  trace message,I see it puts a null character and it creates a problem on side that I send message to.
I checked documentation and it;
A MsgId generated by the queue manager consists of a 4-byte product identifier (AMQ¬ or CSQ¬ in either ASCII or EBCDIC, where ¬ represents a blank character), followed by a product-specific implementation of a unique string. In IBM® MQ this contains the first 12 characters of the queue-manager name, and a value derived from the system clock.
This is my msgId
[image]

any idea why it creates msgId  with null character and how can I solve it?

Comment: MessageID is not a string, it is a 24 byte long byte array. You will need to process it as a byte array. See here for details: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=mqmd-msgid-mqbyte24

Comment: Hi Shashi,Yes I know it is a 24 byte long array,but cant figure why mq generates msgId with a null character.As I know it uses system clock as timestamp or client Ip address ,but both it shouldnt create  msgId with null character.

Comment: I just shared hex format of msgId that generated by mq queue manager.

Comment: The underlined character you pointed out is a hexadeciaml 0, not a null character. Please let us know the issue you are having?

Comment: Null is 00 in hexadecimal and my problem is why mq creates msgId with null character?Receiving application requires msgId without null character,hex 00.

Comment: I think you have two options here: 1) As suggested below by @Doug, generate your own message id and set it when sending messages. 2) Modify your receiving application to handle the "Null" character.

Comment: Thank you Sashi,Now I know there is no rule that msgId cant have null character.So I will ask receiver side to  remove this requirement.I dont think  setting my own message id is a good solution that I can lose uniqueness at one point.Thanks again for ur valuable help

Comment: You cannot create own message id. It is set by broker. Anyway it is byte array. 00 is legal byte value. Don't treat it as string.

Answer (score 1):

MsgId is defined as a byte string, which allows any byte values to be included.
As you have already found, MsgId values generated by MQ use character data for portions of the byte string and add a binary value in the remaining bytes to create a unique identifier.
The binary portion is derived from the system clock and can be expected to contain arbitrary byte values.

If the receiving application has specific requirements for the format of the MsgId and the byte values it can contain, then the putting application will need to generate a MsgId that conforms to those requirements.